# How to resolve a component to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to serve my angular project but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/members/membership-enrollment/membership-enrollment.component.ts:11:14 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Is it missing an @NgModule annotation?
    
    11 export class MembershipEnrollmentComponent implements OnInit {
```

Here's the import section of the app module

```
import { MembershipEnrollmentComponent } from './members/membership-enrollment/membership-enrollment.component';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    //BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TransportationModule,
    MembersModule,
    MembershipEnrollmentComponent,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],

export class AppModule { }
```

What am I missing?

This is the object for the routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'coming-soon', component: ComingSoonComponent },
  { path: 'transportation/enroll',   component: RideEnrollmentComponent },
  { path: 'membership/enroll',       component: MembershipEnrollmentComponent}  
  //{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```

Comment: Why do you have `MembershipEnrollmentComponent` in the imports array? That should probably be in the declarations array.

Comment: I moved ```MembershipEnrollmentComponent``` into the declarations array and stopped getting the error in the console. Now however, I think there's an issue with my routes because I get an error message on the page ```Cannot GET /```.

Comment: remove `pathMatch: 'full'` from this line of code `{ path: '',   component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },`